# QnA Maker rapid insert of Questions and Answers

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

What is the control+key, or method in https://qnamaker.ai to rapidly insert questions and answers -- without having to constantly use the mouse to "Add a new QnA pair"?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately currently you cannot, you must manually press the "+ Add new QnA pair" button.

If you'd like, you can create your QnA pairs separately in a .tsv file, and then upload that file to your QnA service. The QnA pairs will automatically be generated from your file.

https://qnamaker.ai/Content/examples/ExampleFile.tsv

Comment: You can also use Cognitive Services APIs to do some code to manage your QnA Pairs: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/58994a073d9e04097c7ba6fe/operations/58994a073d9e041ad42d9baa